# javax.naming.CommunicationException

Tags: jboss, shutdown

I get the below error while trying to shutdown my jboss server

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException 
[Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 10.10.100.49;
```

nested exception is:

```
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]
 at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:649)
 at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:509)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:188)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 10.10.100.49; nested exception is: 
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
 at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:530)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
 ... 9 more
```

The virtual machine on which the JBoss server is installed was recently copied  to a new virtual machine with a different IP address. Not sure  where the old IP is still referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a search for `10.10.100.49` in your JBoss root folder.

If you're on Unix-like OS, try:

```
find /path/to/jboss/home -type f -exec grep -l '10.10.100.49' {} \;
```